Bollywood movie with aliens
I am looking for a movie that I believed was the Bollywood film Jaadu.
However I have tried to find it using IMDB searches: http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=Jaadu+%281995+film%29&s=all and http://www.imdb.com/find?q=Jaadu&s=tt&ref_=fn_al_tt_mr.
Here is a clip from the movie:


.
Here is an image from the movie:

Can anyone identify this movie?

The only Bollywood Jaadu in IMDB is from 2004, http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4885018/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1. The wikipedia article is not exactly overflowing with information.  Are you sure about the year?

Why is this downvoted?

I believe you are looking for Koi... Mil Gaya from 2003. Looks like it has the extra-terrestrials pictured.

A developmentally disabled young man tries to continue the work his
  father did in communicating with extra-terrestrials from outer space,
  which leads to something miraculous and wonderful.


I am damn sure you are looking for Koi... Mil Gaya (2003) Movie. 

Scientist Sanjay Mehra devises a computer that is capable of
  contacting aliens. His happiness is cut short when the scientists at a
  space-research center scoff at him and refuse to believe his claims.
  While returning home with his pregnant wife, he glimpses an alien
  spaceship, and, in the resulting confusion, he cannot control his car,
  leading to a crash. His wife survives but their unborn child suffers
  brain damage. Years later, their son Rohit Mehra has grown up but has
  thinking capacity of a child. He befriends the town Mayor's daughter
  Nisha, which angers Nisha's suitor Raj, a spoiled brat. One day, Rohit
  and Nisha find Rohit's father's computer in his shed and follow the
  instructions provided. That very evening, their town is paid a visit
  by an alien spaceship that lands someplace nearby and takes off
  shortly afterward. But when the police inspect the footprints, they
  discover that one of the aliens has been left behind.

Krrish (2006) is second part of this movie. In this movie Hrithik Roshan playing role of son of Rohit Mehra and Krrish 3 (2013) is third part. 
